# Trying to sort data in a DataView but nothing happening

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, dataset

I have a DataSet which was holding data that I had extracted from a database table. Relevant excerpts from the controller and model can be seen below

Controller:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds,currentIndex,(int)pageSize,"LD_USER_ROLE");                            
conn.Close();                  
return View(ds);
```

View:

```
@using System.Data
@model System.Data.DataSet

<table>
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    <tr>            

        @foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
        {                
                    <td>@row[column]</td>                 
        }
</tr>        
}
</table>
```

I wanted to alter the code so that the table produced in the view would be sorted by the USERNAME column. To do this I placed the data in a dataview and used the sort method. I then passed the dataview into the view instead of the dataset. When I do this however I end up with the exact same unsorted table as before. What am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds,currentIndex,(int)pageSize,"LD_USER_ROLE");
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
dv.Sort = "USERNAME ASC";                            
conn.Close();                  
return View(dv);
```

View:

```
@using System.Data
@model System.Data.DataView

<table>
@foreach (DataRow row in Model.Table.Rows)
{
    <tr>            

        @foreach (DataColumn column in Model.Table.Columns)
        {                
                    <td>@row[column]</td>                 
        }
</tr>        
}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better sort your data before you fill the DataSet

Comment: I could use an 'order by' line in my SQL queries but I wanted to try and use the DataView instead. I can't see a way of sorting this prior to filling my DataSet though as it seems to me that you need a DataSet to produce a Dataview